# R: ifelse conditioning -> replace with last value for which condition is true

Tags: r, if-statement

Lets say I have this input:

```
input=data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7), y=c(5,5,4,4,3,5))

    x   y
1   2   5
2   3   5
3   4   4
4   5   4
5   6   3
6   7   5
```

Now I want to replace value of x if y < 5. In this case I want to take the last x value for which y => 5

Something like this:

```
attach(input)
xnew=ifelse(y < 5, "last x value for which y=> 5", x)
```

For the example, the output should look like this:

```
   xnew y
1   2   5
2   3   5
3   3   4
4   3   4
5   3   3
6   7   5
```

What do I have to replace `"last x value for which y=> 5"` with for this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try `na.locf` from the `zoo` package. Using your `input` from the comments

```
input=data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), y=c(5,5,4,4,3,5,3,5,3,3,5)) 
input[input$y < 5, "x"] <- NA
library(zoo)
input$x <- na.locf(input$x)
input
#     x y
# 1   2 5
# 2   3 5
# 3   3 4
# 4   3 4
# 5   3 3
# 6   7 5
# 7   7 3
# 8   9 5
# 9   9 3
# 10  9 3
# 11 12 5
```

Comment: yes, this works. thanks! And thank you @akrun for asking the right questions

Answer (score 3):

```
indx <- input$y[tail(which(input$y <5),1)]
input$x[input$y <5] <- indx
 input
 #  x y
 #1 2 5
 #2 3 5
 #3 3 4
 #4 3 4
 #5 3 3
 #6 7 5
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(input)[y <5, x:= y[max(which(y <5))]]
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset:

```
 input=data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), y=c(5,5,4,4,3,5,3,5,3,3,5))

 indx <- which(c(0,diff(input$y<5))==1)
 indx1 <- cumsum(which(input$y <5) %in% indx)
 input$x[which(input$y <5)]<- input$x[indx-1][indx1]
  input
 #    x y
 #1   2 5
 #2   3 5
 #3   3 4
 #4   3 4
 #5   3 3
 #6   7 5
 #7   7 3
 #8   9 5
 #9   9 3
 #10  9 3
 #11 12 5
```

Comment: having some problems applying it to my real dataset. For example: considering a longer input data.frame in which the y value can go below 5 again: `input=data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), y=c(5,5,4,4,3,5,3,5,3,3,5))`, it will always give the value x=3 for y<5, though it should always give the last x value for which y<5, eg. the x values in row 9 and 10 should be x=9. any ideas?

Comment: yes, of course. For the input `input=data.frame(x=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), y=c(5,5,4,4,3,5,3,5,3,3,5))` the output should look like this: `output=data.frame(x=c(2,3,3,3,3,7,7,9,9,9,12 ), y=c(5,5,4,4,3,5,3,5,3,3,5))`